# Executing stored procedure takes too long

Tags: sql

I am trying to update **quantity on hand** for all the inventory items that I have whenever I make a purchase or a sale. I have a stored procedure that does the job. It runs along fine, but when I have for example 2000 inventory items, execution of the query takes more than 45 minutes - any ideas?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateProducts]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LoopCounter INT , @MaxCode INT, 

    SELECT @LoopCounter = MIN(ProductId), @MaxCode = MAX(ProductId) 
    FROM products

    WHILE (@LoopCounter IS NOT NULL
           AND @LoopCounter <= @MaxCode)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Products 
        SET QuantityOnHand  = (SELECT 
                                   ((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(Qty, 0)), 0) 
                                     FROM BILLDETAILS 
                                     WHERE Pid = @LoopCounter) -
                                    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(Qty, 0)), 0) 
                                     FROM InvoiceDetails 
                                     WHERE Pid = @LoopCounter) -
                                    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(Qty, 0)), 0) 
                                     FROM SalesDetails 
                                     WHERE Pid = @LoopCounter))
        WHERE ProductId= @LoopCounter

        SELECT @LoopCounter = MIN(ProductId) 
        FROM Products
        WHERE ProductId > @LoopCounter
    END  
END
```

Comment: Why a SP? Just do an UPDATE.

Comment: 1) What RDBMS are you using? 2) You should try using a `CURSOR`, because the way you have implemented your loop is not efficient at all.

Comment: You are iterating across every row in your table. The performance of this query will deteriorate as the table gets bigger. There are two options: do what @diiN__________ suggests - relational databases are really fast at joins and operating on sets rather than rows - or add a parameter to your proc to only update the rows affected. by the purchase or sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fiqured out why my  query was slow  i had a  column that stores the last update date & time of each row.and i was  updating that column by using a trigger and that affected performance dramatically.

Answer (score 5):

I don't get why you are using a `WHILE` loop to achieve this. You should easily be able to update all products by using `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE p
SET p.QuantityOnHand =
    (ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(b.Qty, 0)), 0) -
     ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(i.Qty, 0)), 0) -
     ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(s.Qty, 0)), 0))
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN BillDetails b ON p.ProductId = b.Pid
INNER JOIN InvoiceDetails i ON p.ProductId = i.Pid
INNER JOIN SalesDetails s ON p.ProductId = s.Pid
```

Comment: i get the following error An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateProducts]
as 
 DECLARE @productIdCursor AS int

 DECLARE
   countProduct 
 CURSOR FOR
  SELECT productId FROM Products

 OPEN   countProduct
  FETCH NEXT FROM countProduct INTO @productIdCursor
 WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN

declare @value decimal(18,2)

set @value=(select      
    (select  ISNULL (SUM (isnull (Qty,0)),0) from BILLDETAILS where Pid = @productIdCursor)          -
    (select  ISNULL (SUM (isnull (Qty,0)),0) from InvoiceDetails where Pid = @productIdCursor)       -
    (select ISNULL (SUM (isnull (Qty,0)),0) from  SalesDetails where Pid = @productIdCursor)
    from Products where ProductId= @productIdCursor)

   update Products 
   set QuantityOnHand  =@value
   where ProductId= @productIdCursor

   print @value
    print @productIdCursor
     FETCH NEXT FROM countProduct INTO @productIdCursor

END

CLOSE countProduct
DEALLOCATE countProduct
```

Just change the type of the varieble "@value" if your need